# Generate more than one date cells in each date_range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, date-range

With [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) one can create time columns for one's dataframe with ease such as

```
df["Data"] = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01 00:00', end='2020-01-05 02:00', freq='H')
```

Which something like this

[image]

I wonder if is it possible to use `date_range` to create, within the range defined (such as the above), 10 entries for each of the time periods. In other words, 10 cells with `2010-01-01 00:00:00`, 10 cells with `2010-01-01 01:00:00`, and so on.

If not, how should one do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `np.repeat`:

```
df['Data'] = np.repeat(pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01 00:00', 
                                     end='2020-01-05 02:00', freq='H'), 
                       10)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use with a list comprehension as below

```
pd.DataFrame({"Data":[d 
                      for i in range(10) 
                      for d in pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01 00:00', end='2020-01-05 02:00', freq='H')]})
```